# Cordova Phonegap 3.5 App displays grey screen after splashscreen has finished loading

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova

I'm currently building an iPhone/iPad App with Cordova Phonegap 3.5 (NOT Phonegap Build) and am experiencing an interesting and unusual bug when publishing the App from Xcode 5.1.1.

Publishing to an iPhone 5C running iOS 7.1.1 works and the App functions/displays exactly as intended.

However when I publish the App to an iPad Retina (latest generation) running iOS 7.1.1 the Splashscreen loads and upon finishing (and subsequently being hidden) defaults to a grey screen instead of displaying the App content.

I've previously published the same App to iPhone/iPad in different versions of Cordova Phonegap without experiencing any issues so I can't fathom what I might be missing/doing wrong (if anything)

Anyone out there experienced similar and/or have any ideas on what could be causing this and how to possibly resolve it?

My thanks in advance.

Comment: If I had to guess, your javascript is failing somewhere along the way, or a plugin is failing. Anything in the console logs? (I'm assuming there aren't any crash logs, though, since the app isn't being terminated.)

Comment: @kerri Hi Kerri Thanks for the response. It appears, from what I can discern so far, to be an issue with a pre-existing copy of jqtouch.css (from rc beta 4 if I remember correctly - the issue is specifically with line 660 concerning the :not selector): #jqt > div:not(.current) {
  display: none;
} If I comment this rule out each screen for the App loads but not without displaying everything in 1 page (each screen of the App stacked under one another)but the rule has to be there in order to hide other screens of the App from being displayed (which works great on an iPhone but not on an iPad).

Comment: Have tried using the latest version of jqTouch (from jqjts.com) but the App displays a black screen after splash screen has loaded on BOTH the iPhone and iPad which is massively frustrating. Not sure where to go from here in order to resolve that

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't do anything with jqTouch, so I'm not going to be much help there. I would find it *odd*, though, that a rule that worked previously under a previous version of Cordova suddenly stopped working now -- Cordova doesn't do anything that should affect CSS styles.

Comment: @KerriShotts Hi Kerri, my apologies for the late reply to your comment (work commitments have been very intense as of late!) I eventually swapped out jqTouch for jQuery Mobile and this fixed the problem entirely. Now the App renders and behaves exactly as intended on both the iPhone 5C and iPad Retina device. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: Glad to hear that you got everything working!